# How do you create a secondary KT1 contact under your TZ address?

Tags: smart-contracts, wallets

I want to have multiple KT1 address on one TZ address(ledger) to delegate to multiple people

Comment: What wallet are you using? see available wallets here: https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016057774-Tezos-XTZ-

Answer (score -1):

**CORRECT ANSWER:**

Be sure to do a test run and only send a small amount of Tezos to make sure you have control of the smart contract.  Once you confirm you can send and receive Tezos from the smart contract, send the rest.  I didn't do that and now Staking facilities is in control of the smart contract and I am waiting for them to send the XTZ back to me.

**Step 1) Download the script to Tezos directory**

curl -O https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/mi-cho-coq/raw/master/src/contracts/manager.tz

**Step 2) create an alias for the tz1 baker address**

./tezos-client add address 'ALIASYOUCHOOSEFORBAKER' 'TZ1ADDRESSOFTHEBAKERY'

**Step 3) create a smart contract making the manager YOURSELF with the --Init command and delegating to the baker with the --delegate command**

./tezos-client originate contract 'SMART CONTRACT ALIAS' transferring 1 from 'ALIAS USED FOR YOUR TZ1 ADDRESS' running "$(cat manager.tz)" --init '"TZ1ADDRESS OF YOUR TZ1 MANAGER"' --burn-cap 0.489 --baker 'ALIAS-YOU-CHOSE-FOR-BAKER-IN-STEP1'

**Example**

**1)**

curl -O https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/mi-cho-coq/raw/master/src/contracts/manager.tz

**2)**

./tezos-client add address STAKINGFACILITIES tz1WpeqFaBG9Jm73Dmgqamy8eF8NWLz9JCoY

**3)**

./tezos-client originate contract DELEGATOR1 transferring 1 from MACK-1 running "$(cat manager.tz)" --init '"tz1b7YSEeNRqgmjuX4d4aiai2sQTF4A7WBZf"' --burn-cap 0.489 --baker STAKINGFACILITIES

Comment: Are you sure? I don't believe `originate contract` accepts a `--baker` option.

Comment: Yes, it does, give it a try.  I did it twice yesterday

Comment: A note, for myself and others, the "baker" option is no longer accepted, you must use "delegate" instead.  Also, make sure to put '"TZ1 address"', with colon and semicolon on both sides or you will get an error