# Delegating from a Kt1 address locked my coins, how can I fix it?

Tags: smart-contracts, transactions, contract, transfer

Might have royally messed up here, but I added an address via command line with
./tezos-client add address stakingfacilities tz1WpeqFaBG9Jm73Dmgqamy8eF8NWLz9JCoY

(for stakingfacilities baker in Germany)

Then initiated a smart contract with
tezos-client originate contract k1 transferring 4633 from k1 
running "$(cat manager.tz)" --init '"tz1WpeqFaBG9Jm73Dmgqamy8eF8NWLz9JCoY"' --burn-cap 0.489

Now when I try to move the tezos with 
./tezos-client transfer 1 from k1 to mack-2

I get the error "Unknown secret key for tz1WpeqFaBG9Jm73Dmgqamy8eF8NWLz9JCoY"

Any idea how to cancel the smart contract or remove the funds?  Transactions don't work on Galleon or Tezbox...

Comment: can you clarify your origination call is correct, as it seems like you are transferring from the same alias you are giving to the contract to be created which shouldn't work

Comment: Then initiated a smart contract with tezos-client originate contract mack-2 transferring 4633 from k1 running "$(cat manager.tz)" --init '"tz1WpeqFaBG9Jm73Dmgqamy8eF8NWLz9JCoY"' --burn-cap 0.489

Comment: what is the address of the new contract you created, have you looked it up on better call dev or some other tool to see if it was created as you expected

Comment: So when I try to send coins from the Kt1 address I get "Unknown secret key for tz1WpeqFaBG9Jm73Dmgqamy8eF8NWLz9JCoY", then when I remove the tz1 address with "./tezos-client forget address stakingfacilities" and try to transfer the coins the error is "no keys for the source contract manager"

Comment: Is there a way to completely cancel the smart contract?

Comment: you can not cancel or modify a smart contract once created

Comment: it is not clear what you were trying to create, need to see what it looks like onchain to decide how to resolve your issue

Comment: Here is the public hash KT1VSiaepk9USGAHDjJQAm4aaYRC6J8dTBHG, originating account tz1b7YSEeNRqgmjuX4d4aiai2sQTF4A7WBZf

Answer (score 2):

You created a contract which can only transfer funds when it receives a call to do so from its "manager" account which was specified at origination and is the only value the contract has in its storage.

The contract can be seen here https://better-call.dev/main/KT1VSiaepk9USGAHDjJQAm4aaYRC6J8dTBHG/operations

You can see that the storage has the value tz1WpeqFaBG9Jm73Dmgqamy8eF8NWLz9JCoY as that is what you provided in the --init of the origination you submitted. The code of the contract you specified only allows the contract to transfer funds when called to do so by the account in storage.

This means you must sign the call with the secret key for tz1WpeqFaBG9Jm73Dmgqamy8eF8NWLz9JCoY. If you don't possess that key then you need to get the holder of that key to make the call for you as effectively they now are in control of the funds in the contract you created.

Best practice would be to only create such contracts with a 0 or minimal transfer to test them before transferring in additional funds.

Comment: Oh dang... hope I can get this figured out then.  I'll send them a message.

Comment: The guy who gave me directions in the Tezos stack exchange told me to use the --init parameter to specify a baker....  https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-do-you-create-a-secondary-kt1-contact-under-your-tz-address/1805#1805

Comment: Does that mean they can import the KT1 address then send the funds back?

Comment: I'm not certain if they can send the call to the "do" entry point without also being the actual manager of the contract. You should search for and if you don't find ask a question such as "How to format the call to the "do" entry point on manager.tz contracts in order to transfer funds to account X" As that is what they will need to do for you.

Comment: crazy, I hope the coins aren't stuck in limboland

Comment: Ok, looks like they can just import the contract.  I did a test on my end and it worked out fine....