# How to delegate XTZ to multiple Validators?

Tags: ledger, xtz, ledger-live

How to delegate XTZ to multiple Validators?

Can I use one Ledger Live account to delegate XTZ to multiple Validators?

Comment: When staking tezos, the entire balance will be used, not parts of it. I assume you will have to open different account for different use of the tezos, like mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post, it shows how to create multiple originated accounts: [How do you create a secondary KT1 contact under your TZ address?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-do-you-create-a-secondary-kt1-contact-under-your-tz-address)

You can also have multiple implicit accounts using the same seed.

Comment: The post you refer to is downvoted, presumably out-of-date.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to split your funds over several accounts. Judging from the [documentation of Ledger](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020435654-Add-your-accounts) it should be easy to add new accounts (presumably you can add several accounts that stores Tezos). You then just have to [set up staking for each account.](https://www.ledger.com/staking-tezos)